# When and how to run VACUUM FULL for large table at PostgreSQL13?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-13

I have a table "transaction_history" which is near about 35GB. Continuously data is inserting and updating on this table. Since table become larger day by day that's why I archived daily data each day. Now there only have 120days data, instead of 4 years data but table still showing it is 35GB because of dead  tuple. Now it is necessary to run VACUUM FULL.

Is it possible to run VACUUM FULL without application connection down, since continuously data is inserting into the "transaction_history" table? If possible then how can we do it without connection down, and how much time it will take?
If not then what would be the best approach for this type of large table? Should I run VACUUM FULL  or VACUUM?

Comment: The locking requirements are well described in the docs.  You start by telling is you need vacuum full, then end by asking us if you need vacuum full.

Comment: pg_repack might be of help: https://pgxn.org/dist/pg_repack/doc/pg_repack.html

Comment: Look at [pg_squeeze](https://github.com/cybertec-postgresql/pg_squeeze).

Comment: Thanks for this extension.